# read property value in Ant

Tags: java, ant

I need to read the value of a property from a file in an Ant script and strip off the first few characters. The property in question is

```
path=file:C:/tmp/templates
```

This property is store in a file that I can access within the ant script via

```
<property file="${web.inf.dir}/config.properties"/>
```

I have two questions:

1. How do I read the single 'path' property from the loaded property file?
2. How do I remove the leading 'file:' from the property value?

Ultimately, I'd like to have access to the following name-value pair within the Ant script:

```
path=C:/tmp/templates
```

Cheers,
Don

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the [propertyregex task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) from [Ant Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) to do something similar.

Answer (score 3):

In Ant 1.6 or later you can use `LoadProperties` with a nested `FilterChain`

```
<loadproperties srcFile="${property.file.name}">
  <filterchain>
    <tokenfilter>
      <containsstring contains="path=file:"/>
      <replaceregex pattern="path=file:" replace="path=" flags=""/>
    </tokenfilter>
  </filterchain>
</loadproperties>
```

This should result in a `path` property being loaded with the string "file:" stripped.

Not tested, caveat emptor...

Comment: <loadproperties> doesn't support a nested <tokenfilter>

Comment: It does, however, support nested <filterchain> -- see http://ant.apache.org/manual/CoreTasks/loadproperties.html

Answer (score 3):

How about just changing the properties file so you can access both the full and simple path?

```
path=C:/tmp/templates
fullpath=file:${path}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use ant's exec task and a system command.

I wrote this up quickly to test the concept:

```
<target name="foo">
  <property name="my.property" value="file:C:/foo/bar"/>
  <exec executable="/bin/cut" inputstring="${my.property}" outputproperty="new.property">
    <arg line="-d':' -f2-"/>
  </exec>
  <echo message="FOO: ${new.property}"/>
</target>
```

Unfortunately this only works if you can build on a system with /bin/cut or some sort of executable you can use.

Comment: Yeah, that'd be a bit of a hassle if you didn't have something like Cygwin installed on your Windows system.